# Link dll from subfolders

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have written a C++/CLI wrapper for some unamanaged dll's (OpenCV). Everything works fine until this point. Now I would like to store the dll's in a subfolder, so the final application structure would look like this:

```
bin\
    MainApp.exe
    wrapper.dll
    Wrapper\library1.dll
    Wrapper\library2.dll
```

Also, I would like to configure this in the Wrapper project, so I don't need to care about this in any other project using wrapper.dll

I have found several posts talking about this, but none of them seems to match my needs:

- Setting the path in app.config file: wrapper.dll does not have an
  app.config file, and I would have to add this reference in every
  executable project using the dll.
- Setting AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath: this could be a workaround, but I'm
  not sure whether it works for unmanaged dll's.
- Using ILMerge: Does it work for unmanaged dll's along with C++/CLI dll?

Ideally I am looking for a property in Project settings to add this subfolder, so every Solution including my project will look for the unmanaged dll's in the right folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the DLL's are usually loaded by Windows, and they're loaded when your application starts. Windows starts by looking at the EXE, finds what DLL's it needs, loads them, and then continues to load DLL's needed by DLL's. This is not specific to C++ or C#.

.Net does affect DLL loading, but that's not applicable to native DLL's.

So, what can you do? One solution is to *not* let Windows load your DLL's. Visual Studio has a `DelayLoad` option. This uses `LoadLibrary` at runtime. And with `dliNotePreLoadLibrary` you can control where it's loaded from. Since this happens at runtime from your DLL, the executables don't need to do anything.

Comment: So in this way, I would need to create some sort of Init method doing the LoadLibrary stuff, and call it from the executables?

Comment: @leandro: No, the compilers sets that up for you. The hook is to return a `HMODULE` for `library1.dll`, which you do by simply returning `LoadLibrary("Wrapper\\library1.dll")`